# Logic App deployment azure Resource group

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, logic-app

I have two Resource group>
1)Azuredev-LogicApp > (Read write permission)
2)Azureacc-LogicApp >(Read permission)

I had created Logic-App in Azuredev-LogicApp  which will update data in SharePoint site(Dev environment having Full permission)
as Recurrence Job at every 6 month i am using send http request to update Modified date.

Now i have to move this Logic App to another resource group Azureacc-LogicApp and Sharepoint site(Acceptance site where i have read permission)

As this is my first app , so like to know how deployment and authorization will work in acceptance environment

Is logic App will work with usercontext similar like MSflow ,and deployment is similar like export import ?